# how to Post to a PHP service,wait for this service to post back to client that file

Tags: php, .net, web-services, post, webclient

I am using `System.Net.WebClient client` in .NET to `post` parameters for PHP web service. The PHP works and creates a file. How can i force the .NET client to wait to that file from php and get it.

1. How would be better for the php to send it exatly to the service that called him?
2. how can i wait for that file in my .Net client?

Comment: Wouldn't just call `getResponse()` to have your code wait for the response?

Comment: In .NET client i can wait, but how i sending (POST) file from PHP service back to client? I can response with string,HTML page,but didn't find how to do that with file.

Comment: Where should i call **getResponse()**? in my code:    `byte[] result = client.UploadFile("http://localhost/test.php", "POST", @"c:\1.zip");
string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, do what You need to be able to create a file. Then create that file, get it contents and `base64_encode` the data. Create an XML (e.g.) and put in the filename, file mime_type and base64 encoded data...

It could look like this (supposing the file is already created and stored somewhere in temp, the filename is stored in variable `$my_filename_with_extension` and its mime_type is stored in variable `$my_file_mime_type` - should You ever need it...):

```
$data = base64_encode(file_get_contents(TEMP_DIR.$my_filename_with_extension));
$xml = '<'.'?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?'.'>';
$xml .= '<response>
    <filename>'.$my_filename_with_extension.'</filename>
    <mime_type>'.$my_file_mime_type.'</mime_type>
    <data>'.$data.'</data>
</response>';
echo $response;
```

Then in .NET application parse that XML and do whatever You need to do with the file data (base64 decode it to get the original file data).

Comment: Sp basically i can use that code to create XML file with all the file data...Do i need the **file name** and mime type for decoding the data for .Net? cant i just use encoding function on the **data** to get the file? another question after i decode it how i transfer it to a FILE in .NET?

Comment: i tried that code and its fails to response that xml... '$data= base64_encode(file_get_contents("/Users/roman/TempCompileFiles/$file/build/Release-iphoneos/MyIpaFile.ipa"));
                $xml= '<'.'?xml version "1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?'.'>';
                $xml .='<response>
                <filename>'./Users/roman/TempCompileFiles/$file/build/Release-iphoneos/MyIpaFile.ipa.'</filename>
                <data>'.$data.' </data>
                </response>';
                echo $response;`

Comment: Its workings,thanks.I had some problems with the xml.I am sending always the same MIME type so i just `echo` the output of the file in `base64` to HTML and then read it in .net...its works slowly but with XML i think it would work the same,no?  also often i am getting unavailable server error (503), is there option to `catch` this error and `POST` again the file?